# Scrollspy for Materialize not scrolling at all with Angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, materialize, scrollspy

I am trying to use scrollspy from Materialize (http://materializecss.com/scrollspy.html) to target each div that is created with ng-repeat.

However, it seems to me as if the `scrollspy` class is not doing anything. Instead of scrolling to that part of the page, the DOM just reloads and points to the portion of the page.

Another problem is that using `href="/#community#sharingLove"` is changing the website URL. Is there anyway for the scrollspy to work without adding to the URL?

```
<div class="full-height row" ng-controller="CommunityController">
    <div class="col l10 main-content">
        <div ng-repeat="principle in acmPrinciples" id ="{{principle.id}}" class="row full-width centering-text section scrollspy">
            <div class ="col-md-12">
                <h4>{{principle.title}}<h4>
            </div>
            <div class ="col-md-12 comm-description-container">
                <p class="paragraph-style larger-font-size">
                    {{principle.description}}
                 </p>
            </div>
            <div class ="col-md-12">
                <video class="responsive-video comm-video-height" controls>
                    <source ng-src="{{principle.videoURL}}" type="video/mp4">
                </video>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col l2 scroll-content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col hide-on-small-only m3 l2 scroll-items">
                <ul class="section table-of-contents">
                     <li><a href="#/community#experiencingGod">Experiencing God</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#/community#sharingLove">Sharing Love</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#/community#conntectingLives">Connecting Lives</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#/community#declaringTruth">Declaring Truth</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have linked included jQuery, bootstrap, and materialize. Last thing: other features of materialize work for me, just not the scrollspy. I also do

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.scrollspy').scrollSpy();
});
```

Comment: add example at https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 2):

I think if you remove #/community from the hrefs it should work. The href should contain the id of the block, not extra url info. Eg try using

```
<a href="#experiencingGod">Experiencing God</a>
```

Comment: Hey  Jacob thanks for answering. You are right. However the problem is with AngularJS controller. Materialize said that the execution starts by using document.ready. However when I do that in my controller it does not work. I have also tried to use $document.ready.function(){} stated in https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$document but no luck. If open the developer console of the html page and type  $('.scrollspy').scrollSpy(); it works. I think that angular executes the function to early, the reason why is because if I put the following code inside setTimeout even for 100ms it works.

Comment: I see. If the controller is generating the page or it's inserted with an ng-include then yes, document.ready is not the right place. You'll have to figure out where the right place to call  $('.scrollspy').scrollSpy(); is. It can be placed in the controller, though angular purists avoid having code that touches the DOM be in the controller. A good approach is to create a directive that calls scrollSpy() when the view is initialized.